# Merging vertices messes up the vertex colors. Is there any fix for that?

Tags: mesh, vertices, vertex-colors

Merging vertices messes up the vertex colors. Is there any fix for that?

Before merging by distance:

[image]

After merging by distance:
[image]

I am using blender 4.0:

Here's the file: [image]

Comment: What version are you use? Can you share the file? I just tested it and didn't face issue

Comment: @Crantisz I'm using blender 4.0 and I just added the .blend file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, I see now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert attribute domain from *Vertex* to *Face corner*:

[image]

[image]

After that, you can merge vertices.

Comment: nice! i ran into this problem too now fixed with Blender 4.0 using `bpy.ops.geometry.color_attribute_convert(domain='CORNER', data_type='FLOAT_COLOR')` but what is this equivalent command in version 2.93?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie it was [introduced in 3.5](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/98003125908858e23e575cf1947cf1b7587716b3)