# How can I preserve face corner colors when doing a limited dissolve?

Tags: python, scripting, edges, faces, vertex-colors

I have imported a model with vertex colors and plugged the Color Attribute to BSDF. Thanks to [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308378/merging-vertices-messes-up-the-vertex-colors-is-there-any-fix-for-that/308381) I am able to merge vertices while preserving vertex colors and face corner colors by converting the Color Attribute to *Face Corner* domain before the merge.

[image]

But when I try to do a Limited Dissolve it dissolves more than I want it to dissolve. I would like to take into account the Face Corner colors. Is that possible? How can I do a dissolve by taking into account Face Corner colors? So it does not dissolve edges where face corner colors on boundaries have sudden color change.

[image]

[Here is the OBJ file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BcVWDSvWLBbBSEgIord1zVswb9Fv-v_X/view?usp=sharing). You can import this obj and then in Shader Editor, add a Color Attribute and plug to BSDF, then the colors will automatically show. Maybe it's something simple I haven't thought about like a python script?

Comment: I've achieved [this](https://imgur.com/a/MB6qPHd) with a series of hacks, if it's what you want.. I wouldn't say it was a tidy procedure for repetition, though....

Comment: @RobinBetts wow yeah that's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Hmm, not sure it is, yet, intersecting edges are not all connected, here's the WIP: https://blend-exchange.com/b/sblskzz4